# If or else logic issue in a loop the return is not valid in c#

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

I need with a if statement logic inside a foreach loop, the problem I am having is that when reading the if statements inside the loop when my loop does the return I am getting the wrong results.

the foreach loop is reading a coming data from a list and then make the decision in the foreach loop based on the if statements

list return method so here in my code for example if data coming in for 5 records and for establishment contains 038 are 4 records and 1 record for establishment 088 when I get the return of that data I get 1 038 then 088 then again 038 and then 088 and so on, and it shouldn't be like that it should return 4 038 and 1 088, so the lotlist return will return a string for example 111920-325 but that is not the problem the problem I am having is the logic of the if statements in the loop

```
public List<string> ParseLot()
        {
            var lotList = new List<string>();
            var establishmentList = GetEstablishmentCode();

            foreach (var lot in GetBarcodeList())
            {
                if (establishmentList.Contains("038"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.LoganSport038Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("072"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.LouisaCounty072Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("086"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Madison086Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("089"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Perry089Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("069"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.StormLake069Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("088"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Waterloo088Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("265"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.GoodLetsVille265Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("087"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.CouncilBluffs087Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("064"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Sherman064Property);
                }

            }

            return lotList;
        }
```

here is the lotstablishment class

```
public class LotEstablishment
{
    // private variable field (access modifiers)
    private const string LoganSport038 = "-244I";
    private const string LouisaCounty072 = "-244L";
    private const string Madison086 = "-244M";
    private const string Perry089 = "-244P";
    private const string StormLake069 = "-244";
    private const string Waterloo088 = "-244W";
    private const string GoodLetsVille265 = "-244G";
    private const string CouncilBluffs087 = "-244C";
    private const string Sherman064 = "-244S";

    // properties
    public string LoganSport038Property => LoganSport038;
    public string LouisaCounty072Property => LouisaCounty072;
    public string Madison086Property => Madison086;
    public string Perry089Property => Perry089;
    public string StormLake069Property => StormLake069;
    public string Waterloo088Property => Waterloo088;
    public string GoodLetsVille265Property => GoodLetsVille265;
    public string CouncilBluffs087Property => CouncilBluffs087;
    public string Sherman064Property => Sherman064;

}
```

calling lot stablishment method

```
public List<string> GetEstablishmentCode()
{
    var establishmentList = new List<string>();

    foreach (var establishmentCode in GetBarcodeList())
    {
        establishmentList.Add(establishmentCode.Substring(36, 3));
    }

    return establishmentList;
}
```

so again, the end result for the lostList return should be based on the if statements inside the foreach loop.

I couldn't find any solid solution in other questions in stackoverflow or google.

Comment: Try to [debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners).

Comment: What is the different between `GetBarcodeList` method being called in `GetEstablishmentCode` and being called in `foreach` loop ?

Comment: Every iteration you check against your full `establishmentList` (which does not change) so it's only logical that it triggers the same `if` statements each iteration.

Comment: Hello @Sinatr, the result of the lotList is a string+stablishment for for example 03142019-244I if is the establishment contains 038 if the GetEstablishmentCode() method has a 038

Comment: hello, bleep-bloop could you add a code solution of my if statement issue inside the loop?

Comment: Could it be that you meant to write ``if (lot.Contains(...))`` in every branch?

Comment: Hello dumetrulo, that resolve the issue by using `if (lot.Contains(...))`, THANKS BRO!!!

Comment: How can I mark this as a solution because @dumetrulo suggestions fixed my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you were calling `Contains()` on the wrong object. The following resolves your issue, calling `Contains()` on `lot` (the running variable in the `foreach` loop):

```
public List<string> ParseLot()
    {
        var lotList = new List<string>();
        var establishmentList = GetEstablishmentCode();

        foreach (var lot in GetBarcodeList())
        {
            if (lot.Contains("038"))
            {
                lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.LoganSport038Property);
            }
            if (lot.Contains("072"))
            {
                lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.LouisaCounty072Property);
            }
            if (lot.Contains("086"))
            {
                lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Madison086Property);
            }
            if (lot.Contains("089"))
            {
                lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Perry089Property);
            }
            if (lot.Contains("069"))
            {
                lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.StormLake069Property);
            }
            if (lot.Contains("088"))
            {
                lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Waterloo088Property);
            }
            if (lot.Contains("265"))
            {
                lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.GoodLetsVille265Property);
            }
            if (lot.Contains("087"))
            {
                lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.CouncilBluffs087Property);
            }
            if (lot.Contains("064"))
            {
                lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Sherman064Property);
            }

        }

        return lotList;
    }
```